# get only current month in month picker other month have to disabled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<div class="col-md-6 form-group"> 
      <label for="">Month : </label>
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text">
       <i class="far fa-calendar-alt">
       </i>
       </span>
       </div>
      <input type="month" class="form-control" id="thismonth" name="thismonth" >
      </div>
</div>
```

how to get the current month in selection and disabled other month.

Comment: I don't see any datepicker in your code, do you build one yourself or use a 3rd-party library? which datepicker lib you are using?

Comment: run code snippet it shows a month picker i want to select a current month in this field and disabled others

Comment: @catcon: They're using the out-of-the-box HTML5 `month` type, which exposes a basic date picker on most modern browsers. They aren't using a custom or 3rd party library.

Comment: @JeremyCaney: thanks, I'm using Firefox and when I run the snippet just a normal input shows up. Look like Firefox does not support for that yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Datepicker for this

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    stepMonths: 0, 
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    firstDay: 1,
}).datepicker("setDate", "+0d" );
```

example : https://jsfiddle.net/scottcwilson/phkkt20e/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can set `Min` and `Max` property for disabled other month and set current month in `value` property.

```html
<label for="start">Start month:</label>

<input type="month" id="start" name="start"
       min="2021-08" max="2021-08" value="2021-08">
```

Refer below link :

http://www.htmlcodes.ws/html-tags/input_type-month.cfm

you can get current month using javascript/jquery